# ref from useRechartToPng() in recharts-to-png library realy slow down page when render chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, ref, recharts

I am using this snippet of code and passing handleDownload method in download button. Ref is also properly passed in barChart. That works, but page is really slowed down by rerendering  and reloading canvas all the time.
I used this
[example.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-lake-dyy8q?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=light&view=editor)
How can I avoid this issue?

```
const [png, ref] = useRechartToPng()

const handleDownload = useCallback(async () => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(png, "graph.png")
    }, [png])
```

[image: console]